# Realizar Búsquedas de palabras por coincidencia en diccionarios en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo dos diccionarios(**data** y **data1**) con palabras, donde **data** esta en la base de datos y **data1** son los datos nuevos(data+nuevos), estos son diccionarios de miles de registros cada uno, por ello se me ocurrió recurrir a *pandas* con **DataFrame** y quizá numpy...

una muestra se vería así:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data  = [
            {"valor": "82388-izquierda_negada"},

            {"valor": "82314-la_fiesta_del_futbol_en_nueva_jersey"},

            {"valor": "83369-cesar_hinostroza_____se_han_violado_mis_derechos___"},

            {"valor": "83427-el_famoso_var__video_"},

            {"valor": "83426-vizcarra_____caiga_quien_caiga__cueste_lo_que_cueste___"},
] 
print ("Dimension data--->", len(data))

data1 = [

        {"valor1": "82388-izquierda_negada"},

        {"valor1": "82314-la_fiesta_del_futbol_en_nueva_jersey"},

        {"valor1": "83369-cesar_hinostroza_____se_han_violado_mis_derechos___"},

        {"valor1": "83427-el_famoso_var__video_"},

        {"valor1": "83426-vizcarra_____caiga_quien_caiga__cueste_lo_que_cueste___"},

        {"valor1":"saint-seiya-soldiers-soul-shaka-virgo-se-luce-imagenes-noticia-392022-1230848"},

        {"valor1":"lluvias-provocan-huaicos-en-via-abancay-andahuaylas-736079/"},

        {"valor1":"jorge-sampaoli-confirmo-reemplazo-sergio-romero-rusia-2018-167251/"},

        {"valor1":"saint-seiya-soldiers-soul-shaka-virgo-se-luce-imagenes-noticia-392022-1230853"},

        {"valor1":"ciudad/pared-de-colegio-se-derrumba-y-aplasta-a-dos-ninos-y-mujer-embarazada-713125/"},
]

print ("Dimension data1 --->",len(data1))

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['valor'])
print (df['valor'][1])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1, columns=['valor1'])
```

Como se puede apreciar en el ejemplo, en **data** tengo 5 registros actualmente y en **data1** tengo 10 registros, significa que, 5 de ellos en **data1** son nuevos y las palabras pueden estar en cualquier orden.

Lo que quiero es, determinar justamente esos nuevos valores en **data1**..

A mi forma de ver me parece que tendría que hacer **busquedas** por *coincidencia* exacta para determinar las palabras nuevas..
Algún método que pueda hacer los mas optimo posible esto con miles de datos que crece en cada momento..!, quizá con pandas, numpy o algún método de búsqueda... No tengo claro como hacerlo, gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` y `data1` no son diccionarios, son listas de diccionarios.

Para los diccionarios en `data` que no son en `data`:

`set(data1)-set(data)`

Para los valores en los diccionarios en `data1` que no son en `data`:

`set([dic['valor1'] for dic in data1])-set([dic['valor'] for dic in data])`

Comment: Realmente lo que quería, muchas gracias por todo @Acccumulation