# Recomendación para encontrar diferencias entre dos diccionarios

Tags: python, python-3.x, diccionarios, comparaciones

Mi problema es que estoy haciendo un programa que recorre directorios y guarda en un diccionario donde la clave principal es el hash md5 y Ruta, Nombre fichero, Fecha y Tamaño. Pasado un tiempo quiero que compare  el estado anterior de los ficheros. Entonces tengo diccionarios con el estado anterior y el nuevo donde tendría algo así:

```
{'d8060194b9eb317dadcbfd5676df62fe': [[b'D:\\Carpeta\\SubCarpeta', b'eula.1028.txt', b'Fri Apr 11 10:07:18 2008', b'3820']], '1106ca5098603387518c1eada04c0542': [[b'D:\\Carpeta\\SubCarpeta', b'eula.1031.txt', b'Fri Apr 11 10:07:18 2008', b'15428']], '62f82dc664ac6e50f65f76eeb59a4a1a': [[b'D:\\Carpeta\\SubCarpeta', b'eula.1033.txt', b'Fri Apr 11 10:07:18 2008', b'10058']], '664f4ea9af608e3dee1012d7c8cbb7fe': [[b'D:\\Carpeta\\SubCarpeta', b'eula.1036.txt', b'Fri Apr 11 10:07:18 2008', b'12246']], 'bbcb29583db900d3b103daca1e2d17b7': [[b'D:\\Carpeta\\SubCarpeta', b'eula.1040.txt', b'Fri Apr 11 10:07:18 2008', b'13912']], '145fe7deeaf08514ff3c16b351f04907': [[b'D:\\Carpeta', b'eula.1041.txt', b'Fri Apr 11 10:07:18 2008', b'5868']], '19de57a008c0a8c04be9864858079902': [[b'D:\\Carpeta', b'eula.1042.txt', b'Fri Apr 11 10:07:18 2008', b'5970']], '99c22d4a31f4ead4351b71d6f4e5f6a1': [[b'D:\\Carpeta', b'eula.1049.txt', b'Fri Apr 11 10:07:18 2008', b'10134']], 'dcd5896a9e154441cffb1d7fb58e6074': [[b'D:\\Carpeta', b'eula.2052.txt', b'Fri Apr 11 10:07:18 2008', b'3814']], 'a1d3f43f55fd38daa6236cb0fccaa498': [[b'D:\\Carpeta', b'eula.3082.txt', b'Fri Apr 11 10:07:18 2008', b'12936']]}
```

Consigo comparar los dicionarios

```
def appseguimientosfiledic():
    newDicFicheros = {}
    lastDicFichero = {}

    lastDicFichero = cargardicionario()               # Cagamos el anterior diccionario
    newDicFicheros = getDicionarioInfoFiles(rootDir)  # Rastrear ficheros y obterner libreria
    if (lastDicFichero == newDicFicheros):
        print ("Todo sigue igual")
    else:
        print ("Hubo algun cambio en la extructura")
        evaluacionDic (lastDicFichero,newDicFicheros)#Evaluamos las diferencias entre diccionarios
        guardardiccionario(newDicFicheros) # Guardamos el diccionario para la proxima
```

Pero me falta alguna idea para encontrar las diferencias

```
def evaluacionDic(lastDic,newDic):
    tGetFiles = time.time()
    print ("Inicia Analisis")

#Codigo de evaluacion

print("------------Tiempo--------------")
print ('Tiempo usado en el analisis:', time.time() - tGetFiles)
print("--------------------------------")
```

**AMPLIACIÓN DE INFORMACIÓN**

Ejemplos de respuestas :
(Es el estado de los fichero de una carpeta por lo que pueden darse los siguientes casos:

- Que se cree un nuevo fichero(Hash nuevo)
- Copia de un fichero (mismo hash pero con nombre o posición cambiada)
- Fichero único borrado(Hash único con una sola posición o nombre cambiado)
- Copia de un fichero borrado(mismo Hash diferentes posiciones o nombres)
- Fecha de modificación cambiada (Solo cambiada la fecha)
- Fichero movido (Cambio en la ruta)
- Fichero modificado (Cambio en hash, fecha, pero nombre de fichero mantenido)

Hay bastantes posibilidades voy a poner el ejemplo de un fichero que ha sido modificado ya que cambio el hash pero el resto se mantuvo.

```
*ESTADO ANTERIOR************************************************************************
{'7a00ac9ed6e731d02e8445dd85cd2479': [[b'D:\\Test2', b'eula.1040.txt', b'Tue Oct  2 21:08:07 2018', b'5118'], [b'D:\\Test2', b'eula.1041.txt', b'Tue Oct  2 21:34:57 2018', b'5118']], '505f60467b194c2f0588d9157514441b': [[b'D:\\Test2', b'eula.1041 - copia.txt', b'Wed Oct  3 08:25:58 2018', b'4658']]}
*NUEVO ESTADO***************************************************************
{'7a00ac9ed6e731d02e8445dd85cd2479': [[b'D:\\Test2', b'eula.1040.txt', b'Tue Oct  2 21:08:07 2018', b'5118'], [b'D:\\Test2', b'eula.1041.txt', b'Tue Oct  2 21:34:57 2018', b'5118']], '5c39f36b44ebe8c574fe6a503ce969db': [[b'D:\\Test2', b'eula.1041 - copia.txt', b'Wed Oct  3 08:27:40 2018', b'4604']]}
*******************************************************************************
SALIDA DESEADA :

El fichero [[b'D:\\Test2', b'eula.1041 - copia.txt', b'Wed Oct  3 08:25:58 2018', b'4658']] a sido MODIFICADO
```

**Estado de la función correspondiente**
Adjunto lo que llevo nuevo de la función que realiza la comparación por ahora es capaz de detectar si se crea o borran ficheros con hash nuevo.

**Función de evaluación como la llevo por ahora:**

```
def evaluacionDic(lastDic,newDic):
    tGetFiles = time.time()
    print ("Inicia Analisis")

for indexnewDic, filenewDic in enumerate(newDic):
    if filenewDic in lastDic:
        if (newDic[filenewDic] == lastDic[filenewDic]): #No me interesan las cosas que no cambian
            #print ("El fichero "+ str(newDic[filenewDic]) + " se encuentra y NO CAMBIO") 
            pass
        else: #Hash igual pero algun cambio hay en la estructura de las listas que cambio
            #print ("El fichero "+ str(newDic[filenewDic]) + " se encuentra pero TIENE DIFERENCIAS con respecto" + str(lastDic[filenewDic]))
            #Tengo que encontrar las diferencias
            # Fecha -> fue abierto no modificado
            # Ruta -> Movido
            # Mas Listas o Menos que antes -> Fue copiado o borrado una copia (Ficheros identicos en las estructura) (Cambio de nombre or/and direccion)
            listnew = newDic[filenewDic]
            listlast = lastDic[filenewDic]
            if (len(listnew) == len(listlast)): #No hay copias nueva del fichero
                for indexnewList, filenewList in enumerate(listnew):
                    if (filenewList == listlast[indexnewList]):             #No me interesan las cosas que no cambian
                        #print ("Este indice del hash NO fue modificado")
                        #No hay copias nueva del fichero
                        pass
                    else:
                        #print ("Este indice del hash FUE modificado")
                        if (filenewList[0] != listlast[indexnewList][0]): #Cambio la ruta
                            print ("Cambio la ruta "+ str(filenewList[0]) + " que anteriormente era " + str(listlast[indexnewList][0]))
                        if (filenewList[1] != listlast[indexnewList][1]): # Cambio el nombre  
                            print ("Cambio el nombre "+ str(filenewList[1]) + " que anteriormente era " + str(listlast[indexnewList][1]))
                        if (filenewList[2] != listlast[indexnewList][2]): # Cambio el fecha  
                            print ("Cambio la fecha "+ str(filenewList[2]) + " que anteriormente era " + str(listlast[indexnewList][2]))
                        #El tamaño no hace falta evaluarlo si cambia el tamaño cambia el MD5
            else: # Mas Listas o Menos que antes (COPIA CREADA O BORRADA)
                print ("Se realizaron/eliminaron copias del fichero")
                #Se borraron
                #   Que fichero se borraron
                #Se crearon
                #   Que ficheros se crearon

    else: # Cambio el hash 2 posibilidad Fichero unico nuevo or Fichero Modificado (EN ESTE MOMENTO NO SE PUEDE SABER)
        print ("El fichero "+ str(newDic[filenewDic]) + " a sido creado/modificado")

for indexlastDic, filelastDic in enumerate(lastDic):
    if filelastDic in newDic: #No Es necesario ya fue controlado en if filenewDic in lastDic: 
        pass
    else:  # Cambio el hash 2 posibilidad Fichero unico borrado or Fichero Modificado (EN ESTE MOMENTO SE PUEDE SABER APROXIMADAMENTE)(ES EL NOMBRE IGUAL Y LA RUTA)
        print ("El fichero "+ str(lastDic[filelastDic]) + " a sido borrado/modificado")
        #Ahora tengo que evaluar si lo que se creo y lo que se borro tienen el mismo nombre porque si es asi fue modificado

print("------------Tiempo--------------")
print ('Tiempo usado en el analisis:', time.time() - tGetFiles)
print("--------------------------------")
```

Aquí dejo el enlace al repositorio para ver el codigo:
https://github.com/minakmostoles/ServerSafe/blob/master/safeServer_02.py
Esta muy por mejorar lo continuare cuando saque algo de tiempo

Comment: Hola MRubio, ¿A qué te refieres con evaluar las diferencias?¿encontrar los hash del nuevo diccionario que no están en el anterior?¿Encontrar los hash que están en uno peo no en el otro (teniendo en cuanta ambos,)?¿Debe comparar también las diferencias de los datos de la lista si el hash no coincide? Sería bueno que agregaras un pequeño ejemplo de dos diccionarios y la salida que esperarías para ellos.

Comment: He añadido mas información de lo que quiero lograr y lo que llevo hasta ahora.  Pero resumiendo estoy haciendo un programa que analice los cambio que esta sufriendo una carpeta. Y por eso lo que me interesa es analizar entre el antes de la carpeta y el después de esta buscando las diferencias. Si se borraron modificaron copiaron etc...

Comment: Probablemente ya habrás encontrado una solución a tu problema, pero te planteo algunas dudas y mi opinión. ¿Por qué resolver un problema complejo solo con diccionarios? Si he entendido bien tus objetivos, ni siquiera estoy seguro de que puedas hacerlo así, al menos con la estructura que planteas. Quizá diseñar una clase (o incluso más de una) sería más apropiado. Por ejemplo, si se copia un fichero, entiendo que dos ficheros tienen el mismo hash. Siendo el hash las keys de los diccionarios, ¿como manejas eso? Ya que un diccionario no puede tener claves repetidas.

Comment: Aquí te pongo el código como lo deje en su día,
https://github.com/minakmostoles/ServerSafe/blob/master/safeServer_02.py

Esta muy por mejorar, su rendimiento es muy malo y no anda terminado.

Uso el hash como key y le adjudico una lista de lista a cada hash con todo los fichero que aparecen. Pero ya te digo el resultado no me gusto mucho. Pero bueno lo hacia por jugar un rato y aprender. Ahora estoy liado y lo he tenido que dejar. Aunque un día lo mejorare.

Answer (score 1):

Seguro que ya lo solucionaste?, quizá  esta pregunta te pueda ayudar en algo: [Diferencia de diccionarios en Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/179899/realizar-b%C3%BAsquedas-de-palabras-por-coincidencia-en-diccionarios-en-python)

Comment: Gracias la verdad hace tiempo que lo hice y se que no lo acabe, se quedo como proyecto inacabado. Pero lo retomare y estudiare tu sugerencia. Recuerdo que lo deje con unos resultados muy malos, es decir hacia su trabajo pero era muy lento mi intención era tener algo como Everything.